# Laravel Socialite: override Provider authorization URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am using Laravel 6.5, [laravel/socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) package, and the [SocialiteProviders/Providers](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders) package

My questions is about [`SocialiteProviders/Providers/Etsy`](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Providers/tree/master/src/Etsy) but could be extended to any of the Providers for Laravel Socialite.

By default, when authorizing with Etsy, all of the [Etsy's permission scopes](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/oauth#section_permission_scopes) are enabled. It is because the API url doesn't have any `scope` query parameters defined yet:

[`urlTemporaryCredentials()`](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Providers/blob/master/src/Etsy/Server.php#L16) method:

```
public function urlTemporaryCredentials()
{
    return 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token';
}
```

In order to restrict some of Etsy's permissions, I need to add scope parameters to return an URL like this:

`https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=email_r%20listings_r`

where the `scope` query param will be setting the permission that I need.

Here is where the authorization is called in my `SocialLoginController.php`

```
protected function getAuthorizationFirst($provider)
{
    $socialite = Socialite::driver($provider);
    return $socialite->stateless()->redirect();
}
```

**Is there a way to override the first URL or prepend query params to it?**

Answer (score 0):

also i'm using Socialite, but for facebook, and the only way i found is this

```php
return Socialite::driver($provider)->fields([
    'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'birthday', 'name'
])->scopes([
    'email', 'user_birthday'
])->redirect();
```

Comment: `Call to undefined method SocialiteProviders\Etsy\Provider::fields()`. Also the `->scope()` is intended for something else than what I want, I believe.

Comment: scope in this case is to declare which filed you want back from the oAuth..

Comment: looking at https://socialiteproviders.netlify.com/providers/etsy.html , at the end, there is 
`$clientId = "secret";
$clientSecret = "secret";
$redirectUrl = "http://yourdomain.com/api/redirect";
$additionalProviderConfig = ['site' => 'meta.stackoverflow.com'];
$config = new \SocialiteProviders\Manager\Config($clientId, $clientSecret, $redirectUrl, $additionalProviderConfig);
return Socialite::with('Etsy')->setConfig($config)->redirect();`
is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

[`SocialProviders`](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Providers) package does not allow custom config on the `Server.php` methods.

The only way as of now is to override the vendor file itself:

**1)** Copy the method(s) from `SocialiteProviders\Etsy\Server` or any provider's Server file

**2)** Paste the method(s) in a new `App\Overrides\Etsy\Server` file, and add your query parameters:

```
namespace App\Overrides\Etsy;
use SocialiteProviders\Manager\OAuth1\Server as BaseServer;

class Server extends BaseServer
{
    public function urlTemporaryCredentials()
    {
        return 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=email_r%20listings_r';
    }
}
```

**3)** Create a new `App\Providers\ExampleServiceProvider` file and add an alias of the `Server` class:

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ExampleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
        $loader->alias('SocialiteProviders\Etsy\Server', 'App\Overrides\Etsy\Server');
    }
}
```

**4)** Register your new Service provider in `config/app.php` :

```
'providers' => [

    //

    App\Providers\ExampleServiceProvider::class,
]
```