# Azure B2C with Laravel Socialite

Tags: php, laravel, azure, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to integrate an azure b2c provider with laravel socialite.
I already add socialite and additional azure provider from socialiteproviders.com

I edited the Provider.php class to change the getAuthUrl schema in order to use tenant instead login.microsoftonline.com and it works fine:

The login page shown and redirected then to setup callback.

In the callback authorization code arrives but the socialite can't use it to obtain the idToken.. (I can calling explicity ../oauth2/v2.0/token but I think that socialite must to take care of it..)

And if I call
\Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::driver('azure')->setConfig($config)->stateless()->user()

I got error from microsoft graph

Or.. if I got manually the idToken and call \Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::driver('azure')->setConfig($config)->stateless()->userFromToken()
it is not recognized.

What's wrong in my flow? Any suggestions to integrate azure b2c in laravel with socialite?

Comment: I have heard editing anything in the `vendor` folder is considered a bad idea. Why did you think the `Provider.php` needed to be modified?

Comment: Never mind, I assume you want to override the functions in the vendor file but it looks like this is not possible and the [whole vendor file has to be overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58857284/laravel-socialite-override-provider-authorization-url).

Comment: the Provider.php in vendor was modified just for fast testing.
If solution was fine, the code will be moved externally..

Comment: I have this exact same problem; no matter what I try I get a '403 Forbidden' on Graph. I'm afraid the socialiteproviders/microsoft-azure package is just not made for B2C, and I am now trying to get [this old project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-php-webapp-openidconnect) working.